# Apply zoom in center of the canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, zooming, center

I need to apply zoom to the javascript canvas which I have badly accomplished by using the following line of code:

```
ctx.scale(2,2) //doubles everything's size
```

Instead of zooming, its obviously doubling the size of the canvas and all of its elements. I'd be okay with this if I got it working like the image below shows:

[image]

Any ideas on how I could accomplish what is depicted in the picture above? I'm not using any external libraries hence making this so difficult. Thanks.

Comment: Use CSS [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) for this.

Comment: Just click the link and find out ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can translate the context by half the canvas size using `ctx.translate()`

EDIT :

```js
var zoomfactor = 2; //set whatever you want as zoom factor
ctx.transform(zoomfactor,0,0,zoomfactor,-(zoomfactor-1)*canvas.width/2,-(zoomfactor-1)*canvas.height/2)
```

Comment: Yeah I've been messing around with ctx.scale and ctx.translate and  I'm afraid I haven't been able to accomplish what I need.

Comment: @Johnny use this for more clarity : `ctx.transform(zoomfactor,0,0,zoomfactor,-(zoomfactor-1)*canvas.width/2,-(zoomfactor-1)*canvas.height/2)` and then you need to redraw your canvas

Comment: @stity it's `ctx.setTransform()`

Comment: I'm getting a "zoomfactor not defined" error. Do I need to use any external libraries for this? 'cause I ain't using none.

Comment: Just defined it as var zoomfactor = 1.15; and it worked just as it was supposed to! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Neither the answer nor the comment is really a solution. Could this please be updated ?